# root encryption with LUKS: root partition not found

Tags: linux, encryption, grub, arch-linux

The layout of my only disk is the following:

`/dev/sda1 for the plaintext boot partition
/dev/sda2 for the encrypted root partition`

My system is ArchLinux and I followed [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Simple_partition_layout_with_LUKS) to set up root encryption (no lvm, no raid). Here is what I did: ran `cryptsetup` on `/dev/sda2` and mapped it into `/dev/mapper/cryptroot`

My `/etc/fstab` looks like this:

`UUID=of /dev/mapper/cryptroot /      ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered,discard 0 1
UUID=of /dev/sda1             /boot  ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered,discard 0 2`

In my `/etc/default/grub` I altered one single line to be:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=UUID of /dev/sda2:cryptroot:allow-discards"`

In the `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` the hooks look like this:

`HOOKS="base udev autodetect modconf block encrypt filesystems keyboard fsck"`

Finally, I did not forget to run `mkinitcpio -p linux` and `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` respectively.

I have enumerated my actions in such a brisk manner because I have previously been successful at configuring encryption for my root fs. So, in the end I get the following error:

`ERROR: device *UUID of /dev/mapper/cryptroot* not found. Skipping fsck.
ERROR: unable to find root device *UUID of /dev/mapper/cryptroot*
You are being dropped into recovery shell`

The weird thing is that it attempts to look for the unencrypted `/dev/mapper/cryptroot` and yet it doesn't ask me for the password (which I created when `cryptsetup`'ing on `/dev/sda2` at the beginning). So, naturally it cannot find the unencrypted block device because it did not ask me for its password in the first place. Could you please tell me what have I configured wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I had success with `cryptdevice=/dev/disk/by-uuid/<UUID_OF_LOGICAL_DEVICE>:cryptroot root=/dev/mapper/cryptroot` for the additional kernel options in GRUB.

It's worth noting that if you're doing this without precision of copying and pasting the UUID (such as in a console/tty), you might have typo'd that. Here's a one-liner, that also sucks to type from console, but might prove easier.

`sed "s/\(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=\"\)/\1cryptdevice=\/dev\/disk\/by-uuid\/$(blkid -o value -s UUID /dev/<LOGICAL_DEVICE>):cryptroot root=\/dev\/mapper\/cryptroot/" /etc/default/grub > ~/grub.defaults && mv ~/grub.defaults /etc/default/grub`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing /etc/crypttab  the cpio hooks are pointing to a partition the OS is un-awares of

*/etc/crypttab*

%{UUID of /dev/mapper/cryptroot} /      ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered,discard,luks -  0 1

then rerun grub update

Comment: the ' - '  is intentional and forces password interogation short of a valid keyfile for a valid active keySlot

Comment: Thank you, but `crypttab` contains a comment "do not list your root (/) partition here, it must be set up beforehand by the initramfs (/etc/mkinitcpio.conf)" which I understand to be the reference to the fact that you have to add a hook. Do I misunderstand this comment?

Comment: By the way, your current answer uses some hybrid of `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/crypttab` syntax, see the example for `/etc/crypttab` [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/System_configuration#crypttab)

Comment: `/etc/crypttab` is located on the very root partition that fails to decrypt, so this can't be a solution to decrypt it.